# module in F# interactive startup file

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have a `finit.fsx` file to be load at fsi.exe startup like:

```
#r xxxx
type xx = xxx
module Util = 
   let cd path = xxxx
   ...
```

After start fsi.exe, it is loaded as

```
namespace FSI_0002
  module Util = begin
    val cd : string -> unit
  ...
  end
```

The problem is how can I use `module util`? I cannot `open Util` or use `cd` directly. 
To further puzzle me, if I put a namespace at the top line like `namespace Test`, In fsi.exe, it is loaded as

```
namespace FSI_0002.Test
  val cd : string -> unit
  ...
```

Where is the `Module Util`? I then have to `open Test;;` then `Util.cd`.

Is there a way to define module in the F# startup script and auto open the module? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can explicitly specify that all code in the `.fsx` file is in some module (say, `Main`) and add the `AutoOpen` attribute to the module:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Main

let foo = 10
```

When you then `#load` the file, the `foo` value should be visible at the top-level.

Answer (score 2):

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Util = 
   let cd path = ...
```

Comment: this needs to be at top. If I have type definition above `module Util`, it does not seem work...

Comment: @matlabdbuser - The difference is that if you use `=`, you're creating a module inside the (implicit) module added by F# (based on the file name). Without `=`, it overrides the default module name.